# Strange Windows/Python/Popen Issue

Tags: python, windows, popen

When I run the following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('dir', shell=True)
```

The result always shows me the contents of `C:\`, no matter what directory I started the Python interpreter in.  I even tried this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('dir', shell=True, cwd='C:\\foo\\bar\\baz')
```

and that doesn't work either.  I'm also having trouble building an application using Scons (Python-based build tool),  for what appears to be the same reason:

```
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fobuild\Animation.obj /c src\Animation.cpp /TP /DSFML_STATIC /EHsc /MD /Zi /Ideps/Box2D_v2.2.1 / Ideps/LuaJIT-2.0.2/src /Ideps/SFML-2.0/include /Ideps/include /nologo
Animation.cpp
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src\Animation.cpp': No such file or directory
scons: * [build\Animation.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Note that src\Animation.cpp actually *does* exist.  I assume this happens b/c `cl.exe` is running from `C:\` instead of the actual location where the Python interpreter is running from.

I thought this might be a problem with my environment variables, but I checked them and everything seems OK.  I also removed/reinstalled Python, to no avail.

What's going on here?

Comment: What's the output of `print(os.getcwd())`?

Comment: Also try it without `shell=True`.  It can have odd behaviour when running a shell and you generally don't need it.

Comment: drop unnecessary `()` around arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!  Problem was the AutoRun setting in the registry...not sure how that got set, but it was.  To resolve this, go to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

In the registry, and delete the AutoRun setting.  My AutoRun looked like this:

`cd C:\`

Which was completely screwing everything up.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape '\' or use raw string (`r'....'`).

```
>>> 'C:\foo\bar\baz'
'C:\x0coo\x08ar\x08az'
>>> r'C:\foo\bar\baz'
'C:\\foo\\bar\\baz'
```

Comment: Or alternatively use / as a directory separator.

Comment: Transcription error.  In my code I actually do escape the reverse slash.

Comment: What is the output of `import os; print(os.getcwd())`